# Using houghline transform to identify straight lines in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform, scikit-image

I have tried HoughLine transform from both openCV and skimage

and I'm unable to identify the straight lines from this image.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/imagedata-toi/houghlines5.png

I referred to the code given in the documentations

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

And I keep detecting a single line.

I even tried the sudoku image shown in the tutorial and I keep detecting a single line.

What am I doing wrong ?

(I'm using python3 if that is relevant)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('edges.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)
cv2.imwrite('houghlines3.png',img)
```

[image: Code Output]

Comment: you cannot discuss problems with your code without providing your code... we cannot tell you what you're doing wrong because we don't know what you're doing. it is most likely due to wrong parameters, which again we don't know.

Comment: Hi I have added the code. Its the exact same one shown in the OpenCV tutorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hough lines in OpenCV/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541551/hough-lines-in-opencv-python)

Comment: The issue is the same as in the duplicate i linked to, since in both cases Hough Transform is detecting multiple lines, yet you are only drawing the first line detected such as in "for rho,theta in lines[0]:"

Comment: So how would I change it to draw all the lines in Hough Transform  ? (The link shows HoughP transform)

Comment: Just like done in the duplicate: instead of "for rho, theta in lines[0]" you will use "for x in range(0, len(lines)): 
    for rho,theta in lines[x]:"