# Is the any way to detect table with pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I have tried to extract table data from the image and insert to csv. I use by tesseract

can anyone tell me how to detect table data from the image

I have this image:

[image]

Comment: You can try hough line transform of opencv. Otherwise no inbuilt way to do in tessersact.

Comment: How to do line transform. do you have any script like this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541551/hough-lines-in-opencv-python) out.

Comment: If its a single image do it by hand, if you have lots of similar data, train your own convolutional neural network to get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Check this open source library https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber. This has shown good promise in extracting table data. You will get the texts in the table as a list of lists which is very useful. Apart from that, you can get the coordinates of the cells also which gives provisions for any post-processing.

One drawback is that it works only for digital pdfs.

Comment: I dont have PDF, i am talking about the image like jpg, png file.