# Multiple Horizontal & Vertical Lines are not showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, hough-transform

Here i am trying to find the height of the water using opencv, hough transform. This program consist of canny edge detection, background subtraction, then the hough transform and height estimation. Then using the height it plot the graph.But this only detects the vertical lines. Multiple Horizontal & vertical lines are not showing. Any problem with the code?

Output of the program:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import imutils 
import argparse
import cv2
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scaling_factorx = 0.8
scaling_factory = 0.8

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)
count = 0
height = []

while(1):

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if frame is None:
        break
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 1, 100)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho = 1,theta = 2*np.pi/180,threshold = 10,minLineLength = 100,maxLineGap = 10);
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines[0]:
            dot1 = (line[0],line[1])
            dot2 = (line[2],line[3])
            cv2.line(frame, dot1, dot2, (255,0,0), 3)
            length = line[1] - line[3]
            print(length)
            height.append(length)

    cv2.imshow("output", frame)

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx = scaling_factorx, fy = scaling_factory, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', fgmask)

    gray_vid = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)

    edged_frame = cv2.Canny(frame, 1, 100)
    cv2.imshow('Edges', edged_frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q'):
        break

x = []
y = []

for i in range(len(height)):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(height[i])

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(x,y) 
plt.plot(x, y)  
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
plt.ylabel('y - axis')  
plt.title('Height') 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only draw one line because your for loop over lines is only looping over a single line.

```
if lines is not None:
    for line in lines: #for each line...not just one of them
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            dot1 = (x1,y1)
            dot2 = (x2,y2)
            cv2.line(frame, dot1, dot2, (255,0,0), 3)
            length = y1 - y2
            print(length)
            height.append(length)
```

Comment: When i did the change and run the program this shows 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    dot1 = (line[0],line[1])
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
[ WARN:1] terminating async callback

Comment: take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541551/hough-lines-in-opencv-python). i just edited my answer to look more like it

Comment: still it showing those error, changed parameters, values, but still the same

Comment: you should not be using an index into `line` anymore so if you still have the same error, you may have missed updating something. I have a working example with a single image using the code in my answer.

Comment: its working, i mean its showing horizontal and vertical lines. By changing the max and min value will i be able to get more lines??